# Java DateFormat for 2 millisecond precision

Tags: java, time, date-format

I'm having a problem with trying to get the DateFormat library to give me a String with the date to be formatted with 2 millisecond places instead of the usual 3.  I realize this is more  along the line of centi-seconds, but afaik Java doesn't support that.

Here is some code to show the problem I am having.  I would expect it to output to two milliseconds, but it outputs three.

```
public class MilliSeconds {
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_2MS_Digits = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'";
private static DateFormat dateFormat2MsDigits = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_2MS_Digits);

public static void main( String[] args ){
    long milliseconds = 123456789123l;
    System.out.println(formatDate2MsDigits(new Date(milliseconds)));
}

public static String formatDate2MsDigits(Date date)
{
    dateFormat2MsDigits.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT")));
    return dateFormat2MsDigits.format(date);
}}
```

outputs:

> 1973-11-29T21:33:09.123Z

I could just parse the resulting string and remove the digit I don't want, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to achieve this.  Does anyone know how to get this to work, or why it is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry. Acording to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> the number of letters for number components are ignored except it's
>   needed to separate two adjacent fields

...so I don't think there's a direct way to do it.

I would use a separate format only for `SSS` and call `substring(0, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about having a separate format for the milliseconds.

Comment: Maybe less complicated to do the whole thing in one go, but without the Zulu time indicator.  Then just trim off the last character and add on the Z.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to deduce why is the problem happening, but after replacing date format with [yoda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), the generated time string had correct number number of seconds [ only 2].

Comment: I think it's only the method contract. When you say S it's the miliseconds from 1 to 3 digits. SS is ms from 2 to 3 digits. SSS is always with 3 digits. Maybe yoda has another contract.

Comment: @helios, you are right. For SS, it will display only 2 digits only if 3rd digit is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would include [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and use something like:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT_2MS_FMT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'";

private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT_2MS_DIGITS = DateTimeFormat
        .forPattern(DATE_FORMAT_2MS_FMT).withZoneUTC();

public static String formatDate2MsDigits(Date date) {
    return DATE_FORMAT_2MS_DIGITS.print(date.getTime());
}
```

If you don't want the additional dependency, I think twiddling the result string from `.format(...)` is the only way.